# How to redirect standard and error output in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to redirect standard and error output in F#

```
let RunProcess (processInfo : ProcessStartInfo) =
    let str = StringBuilder()
    processInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
    processInfo.RedirectStandardError <- true
    let p = new Process()
    p.StartInfo <- processInfo
    p.OutputDataReceived.Add(fun x -> str.Append(x.Data + Environment.NewLine) |> ignore)
    p.ErrorDataReceived.Add(fun x -> str.Append(x.Data + Environment.NewLine) |> ignore)
    p.Start() |> ignore
    p.BeginOutputReadLine()
    p.BeginErrorReadLine()
    str.ToString()
```

When I do that nothing happen.

However when I set processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput to false things are displayed in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.Start()` does not wait for the started process to finish execution.
An additional `WaitForExit` would be required to do that otherwise chances are high you are going to call the StringBuilder ToString before anything has been written to it at all.

Comment: I actually have a WaitForExit() in my code but I accidentally removed it while "cleaning" my code before posting it on StackOverflow.

Comment: At the end I solved it by returning
p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use:

```
let inline tee    f v   = f v ; v
let inline  (|>!) v f   = f v ; v

let RunProcess (startInfo : ProcessStartInfo) =
    let bufferOutput                      = new StringBuilder()
    let bufferError                       = new StringBuilder()
    let dataHandler               handler = DataReceivedEventHandler(fun sender args -> try handler args.Data with _ -> ())
    let consume   (sb: StringBuilder)     = sb.ToString() |>! (fun _ -> sb.Clear() |> ignore)
    let append    (sb: StringBuilder) txt = sb.Append(txt + "\n") |> ignore
    let outputHandler                     = append bufferOutput   |> dataHandler
    let errorHandler                      = append bufferError    |> dataHandler
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput      <- true
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput     <- true
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError      <- true
    startInfo.UseShellExecute            <- false
    let proc                              = new Process(
                                                StartInfo           = startInfo
                                              , EnableRaisingEvents = true     )
    outputHandler                        |> proc.OutputDataReceived.AddHandler
    errorHandler                         |> proc.ErrorDataReceived .AddHandler
    let r                                 = proc.Start                 () 
    do                                      proc.BeginOutputReadLine   ()
    do                                      proc.BeginErrorReadLine    ()
    do                                      proc.WaitForExit           ()
    let output                            = (consume bufferOutput).Trim()
    let error                             = (consume bufferError ).Trim()
    ((if proc.HasExited then proc.ExitCode else -99999), output, error)
```

Comment: I find lining everything up like that to be aesthetically displeasing because of the vast distance between `let bufferOutput` and `= new StringBuilder()`. It breaks the flow of reading. I have no problems with lining up `let bufferOutput` and `let bufferError`, but I don't think the `let bufferOutput` line should be lined up with `startInfo.RedirectStandardInput`.

Comment: @rmunn I line everything in my code in an almost compulsive way not because I am compulsive and not even for aesthetic reasons, but because it allows me to use the natural pattern recognition abilities of the brain to detect similarities and differences in the code so I can find inconsistencies and also patterns that can be generalized. For you, the gap breaks the flow of reading, for me, it makes reading so much easier. I do not have to parse looking for a `=` or a `<-` to differentiate left side from right side. It takes some getting used to it, but then it becomes essential.

Comment: Showing how I would write this is probably easier than explaining it, so here's a gist. Note that I have still lined up the parts of the code that are similar to each other, but there's a much more natural left-to-right flow of each line while still keeping the vertical groupings of similar parts: https://gist.github.com/rmunn/11dc4427be513f4ce6c6fb1408ddb62d

Comment: Thanks, for sharing. Like I said, I find my version easier to read. I usually do not read from left to right but look more to the right side because that is where the expressions are. On the left side, the gap helps me differentiate functions from simple values because of the parameters, which sometimes I also align to the right to make it more evident.

Comment: I added more alignment changes to accentuate (maybe exaggerate) the point. I tend to experiment with alignment to see what helps me more. Now all expressions are on the right side, before, the calls `proc.BeginOutputReadLine()` were breaking that rule.

Comment: In case sombody wants it typed: `.OutputDataReceived.AddHandler (DataReceivedEventHandler (fun (obj : obj) (data : DataReceivedEventArgs) ->  Console.WriteLine data.Data))`